# Button not responding

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

my button listener does not perform an action when updating information, how to solve it?
this is my button in editcontroller class:

```
 @FXML
    private void patientSaveOnAction(ActionEvent event){
        LocalDate date = dpDateOfBirth.getValue();
        Date today = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        int sex = radioMale.isSelected() ? 1 : radioFeMale.isSelected() ? 2 : 0;
   isNotNull(); 
if (validatePhoneNumber() && validateMail() && validateName() && age()){
    //validatePhoneNumber() && validateMail() && validateName() && age()
   //patientGetway.update(new Patient(0,copyImage(),tfName.getText(),date,sex,tfEmail.getText(),tfPhone.getText(),taAddress.getText(),dateFormat.format(today)))
if (patientGetway.update(new Patient(0,copyImage(),tfName.getText(),date,sex,tfEmail.getText(),tfPhone.getText(),taAddress.getText(),dateFormat.format(today)))){
           resetForm();
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                  alert.setTitle("Patient updated successfully");
                  alert.setHeaderText("Patient updated");
                  alert.setContentText("Patient updated successfullly");
                  alert.showAndWait();
        }
         }     
   }
```

these are my methods in the same class

```
private boolean isNotNull(){
    boolean isValid = false;
    if (tfPhone.getText().isEmpty() ||tfName.getText().isEmpty()||tfEmail.getText().isEmpty()||taAddress.getText().isEmpty()) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("All field required");
        alert.setHeaderText("All fields are required");
        alert.setContentText("All text fields are required. please fill all text field");
        alert.showAndWait();
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

these method are for validating information on date,email,names and phone number
the methods are well set but are not being updated

```
private boolean age(){
    String age = "";
    LocalDate birthdate = dpDateOfBirth.getValue();
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

    if(birthdate.isAfter(now)){
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
alert.setTitle("Validate the date of birth");
alert.setHeaderText(null);
alert.setContentText("please put a valid date");
alert.showAndWait();
return  true;
    }else{
    age = String.valueOf(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(birthdate, now));

     return false;
    }
}
private boolean validateMail(){
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._]*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+([.][a-zA-Z]+)+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(tfEmail.getText());
    if(m.find() && m.group().equals(tfEmail.getText())){
    return true;
    }else{
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.setTitle("validate email");
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText("please provide the valid email address");
    alert.showAndWait();
    return false;
    }
}
private boolean validateName(){
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(tfName.getText());
    if (m.find() && m.group().equals(tfName.getText())) {
        return true;
    }else{
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
alert.setTitle("validate your name");
alert.setHeaderText(null);
alert.setContentText("please provide the valide name");
alert.showAndWait();
return false;
    }
}    
private boolean validatePhoneNumber(){
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(tfPhone.getText());
    if (m.find() && m.group().equals(tfPhone.getText())) {
        return  true;
    }else{
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.setTitle("validate phone number");
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText("please provide the valid phone number");
    alert.showAndWait();
    return false;
    }
}
```

this is the update method in another class that i called in my class

```
public boolean update(Patient patient) {
    DBConnection connection = new DBConnection();
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    boolean isUpdated = false;
    if (patientBLL.isValid(patient) && patientBLL.isUnique(patient)) {
        System.out.println(connection.geConnection());
        con = connection.geConnection();
        try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement("update patient set thumbnail=?,name=?,date_of_birth=?,sex=?,email=?,phone=?,address=? where id=?");
            pst.setString(1, patient.getThumbnail());
            pst.setString(2, patient.getName());
            pst.setString(3, String.valueOf(patient.getDateOrBirth()));
            pst.setInt(4, patient.getSex());
            pst.setString(5, patient.getEmail());
            pst.setString(6, patient.getPhone());
            pst.setString(7, patient.getAddress());
            pst.setInt(8, patient.getId());
            pst.executeUpdate();
            pst.close();
            con.close();
            connection.con.close();
            isUpdated = true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PatientGetway.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return isUpdated;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. For quick and efficient help, please post [mcve]. I find mcve  a very useful technique. Not only it makes helping much easier, it 
is a powerful debugging tool. It many case, while preparing one, you are likely to find the problem.